# Can we fill the plane with a certain operation?

Tags: rational-numbers, plane-geometry, tiling

**Background:**

Paint the origin $(0,0)$ black in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $S$ be a set $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ~|~ x^2 + y^2 =1 \}$.

Paint $S$ black.

Paint $(u,v) +S$ black for all $(u,v) \in S$.

(Then we can easily check that all points with $\|(x,y)\| \leq 1$ is painted.)

Paint $(u',v') + S$ black for all the previous black painted points $(u',v')$.

If we repeat this process, then we can paint all points in the plane.

Especially, we can find out that every points $(x,y)$ is painted 
in the finite process.

**Question:**

I shall do almost same thing.

Denote $O=(0,0)$, $A=(1,0)$.

Let $S'$ be a set $\{ B \in S ~|~ 
\frac{\angle BOA}{2\pi} \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.

Paint the origin $(0,0)$ black.

Paint $(u,v) + S'$ black for all the previous black painted points $(u,v)$.

Repeat this process.

Then, can we paint all points in the plane? i.e.,

For every point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$,
is $(x,y)$ painted in the finite process?

Comment: Note that $S'$ is countable, and so is the set of painted points at each step of the process. And to get all the points that get eventually painted, you take a countable union of countable sets. Conclusion?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much!